# Spark SQL - why use managed Spark table instead of Hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Please excuse what is likely a v novice question - just trying to wrap my head around Spark.

In Spark, you have managed tables, where the table data and metadata are both managed by Spark.

Specifically on managed tables, why would anyone want to create a Spark managed table instead of just creating the table in Hive? What are the benefits of storing any tables within Spark, when you have Hive which I believe can integrate smoothly with Spark? Thanks.